# regex for alphanumeric and alphabets

Tags: regex

I m looking for regex where it accepts alphanumeric characters and alphabets

Example

```
RAM123 -positive
ram123 - positive
rAm123-positive
Ram -positive
ram - positive
123-negative
```

I have tried using [0-9a-zA-Z].* but it also accepts  numeric characters..which should not be..thr regex should accept any alphanumeric/ alphabets other than nums and special charcters

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a negative lookahead assertion at the start.

```
^(?!\d+$)[\da-zA-Z]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cE4cA0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\da-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][\da-zA-Z]*$
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/17